# Build Tesseract OCR library with Qt 5.8 Mingw

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, ocr, tesseract

I download the Tesseract library for MinGW from [here](https://github.com/zdenop/tesseract-mingw) and the library compiled already and contains and example that should work directly and have the dll files and everything seems to be fine first when I use the example .pro file in my Qt 5.8 Mingw and build it I got this errors

```
:-1: error: cannot find -llept
:-1: error: cannot find -ltesseract
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the .pro file code here

```
QT          =

TARGET      = ApiExample
TEMPLATE    = app

OBJECTS_DIR += temp
MOC_DIR     += temp
UI_DIR      += temp
RCC_DIR     += temp

SOURCES += ApiExample.cpp
LIBS    += -llept -ltesseract

win32: {
    CONFIG  += console
    DESTDIR = ./bin
    INCLUDEPATH += ./include/
    LIBS += -lws2_32 -L./lib
    DEFINES += WINDOWS __BLOB_T_DEFINED
}
```

then i try to edit the .pro file and remove this line

```
LIBS    += -llept -ltesseract
```

and add this

```
LIBS    += -L$$PWD/bin\
    libtesseract-3 \
    liblept-3 \
```

I clean and build the result it Build successfully with no errors 
I try to run now when the application start it crash got this error

```
APIExamople.exe has stopped working and two buttons Debug and close program
```

so I try to add all the dll files in the bin folder ! to be

```
LIBS    += -L$$PWD/bin\
        libtesseract-3 \
        liblept-3 \
        libgcc_s_dw2-1 \
        libgif-4 \
        libjbig-1 \
        libjpeg-8 \
        libpng15-15 \
        libstdc++-6 \
        libtiff-3 \
        libtiffxx-3 \
        libwebp-2 \
        libmingwm10 \
        libzlib1 \
```

start to build run and the same it crash again 
I copy all dll files to the debug dir try to build and run in release mode all the same crash 
i run Qt debug to see where the error from i found it on that line from the example code i use

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* lang = "eng";
    const char* filename = "D:/b.jpg";

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess; // debug stopped here on this line
    tess.Init(NULL, lang, tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);

    FILE* fin = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fin == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open " << filename << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(fin);

    STRING text;
    if (tess.ProcessPages(filename, NULL, 0, &text))
    {
        std::cout << text.string() << std::endl;

    }
}
```

stop on the line of **tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;** 
I use another pre-build library for MSVC and link it's library in qt and it compiled and run and works no problem with the same example code i use for MinGW now 
what I did wrong make this crash?

**Update:**
I try to remove this part from .pro file

```
win32: {
    CONFIG  += console
    DESTDIR = ./bin
    INCLUDEPATH += ./include/
    LIBS += -lws2_32 -L./lib
    DEFINES += WINDOWS __BLOB_T_DEFINED
}
```

and replace it with this all .pro file now

```
    QT          =

TARGET      = ApiExample
TEMPLATE    = app

OBJECTS_DIR += temp
MOC_DIR     += temp
UI_DIR      += temp
RCC_DIR     += temp

SOURCES += ApiExample.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
LIBS    += -L$$PWD/bin\
        libtesseract-3 \
        liblept-3 \
        libgcc_s_dw2-1 \
        libgif-4 \
        libjbig-1 \
        libjpeg-8 \
        libpng15-15 \
        libtiff-3 \
        libtiffxx-3 \
        libwebp-2 \
        libmingwm10 \
        libzlib1 \
```

the result the crash dialog not appear but it crash and give me this error in Qt Application output

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I face this error when I not add DLL files in the .exe dir but now I add them and i got the same error 
please I need any hint to solve my problem and I still try now 

**update**
I try to compile it using QT 5.5.1 but I got some problems and errors in mingw32-make step so if anyone try to compile it using MinGW can you add the link here to the compiled library to use it directly?

Comment: I don't know about QT-Mingw but with regular Mingw, I use: http://pastebin.com/J5TREgg4

Comment: can you give me the link of the compiled library that you use ?